# Bad request on Create educationSubmissionResource on Microsoft Teams for Education

Tags: php, microsoft-teams

We have develop an integration with Microsoft Teams for Education and all API calls work correctly except for the Create educationSubmissionResource call when a student submits a task.

We have created an assignment with the `allowStudentsToAddResourcesToSubmission` flag set to true and when a student submits the assignment we execute the following code:

```
$graph = new Microsoft\Graph\Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($student->accessToken);

$submissionResource = new Microsoft\Graph\Model\EducationSubmissionResource();
$linkResource = new Microsoft\Graph\Model\EducationLinkResource();
$linkResource->setLink($link);
$linkResource->setDisplayName(mb_substr($title, 0, 100)); // as the maximum length is 100
$linkResource->setODataType('#microsoft.graph.educationLinkResource');
$submissionResource->setResource($linkResource);

$graph
    ->createRequest(
        'POST',
        "/education/classes/{$courseId}/assignments/{$courseWorkId}/submissions/{$submissionId}/resources"
    )
    ->addHeaders(["Content-Type" => "application/json"])
    ->attachBody($submissionResource)
    ->execute();
```

The response is always the same (identifiers are hidden):

```
Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/classes/[...]/assignments/[...]/submissions/[...]/resources` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

{"error":{"code":"10017","message":"Bad Request.","innerError":{"date":"2023-11-29T15:14:35","request-id":"[...]","client-request-id":"[...]"}}}
```

But it's not specified anywhere what is the problem. Has anyone found themselves in a similar situation and have some hints?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please validate the access token? Ensure that the access token you're using is valid and has the necessary permissions to perform the operation.
Also verify the identifiers & make sure that the courseId, courseWorkId, and submissionId you're using in the request URL are correct and valid.

Comment: The access token and identifiers are valid because prior to this we submit the assignment with the same access token, courseId, courseWorkId and submissionId identifiers and the query goes through correctly.

Comment: This kind of error message shows up when the server cannot not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured that out reading the error message, but the real issue is what's the problem? I'm using the API so a malformed query should not be the case, therefore it must be the data, but the data is a link and a name limited to 100 characters. I don't understand why this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some days of investigating looks like the problem was that every time a student did the task we sent the same link resource to Microsoft Teams and the error originates only after the first time.

Conclusion: Teams responses with an error if you send the same resource to a submission that already has it.